# how to write xpath to query an xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

i have an xml file which i want to query from a php page.Actually the file contains username and password of users.I want to query the file and see if there is a match for a username and password.Here are my codes for the php page:

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


$xml = simplexml_load_file('users.xml') or 
    die("error :cannot create object");
    print_r($xml);


$result = $xml->xpath("/user[username=".$username."] and //user[password=".$password."]");

foreach ($result as $node){
    echo $node->id;
    echo $node->username;
}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<user>
<id>1</id>
<username>mygirl</username>
<password>mygirl1234</password>
<email>mygirl@hotmail.com</email>
</user>
```

Exceptions

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid expression in C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Freshshop Free Website
>   Template - Free-CSS.com\freshshop\successfullogin.php on line 11
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Freshshop Free
>   Website Template - Free-CSS.com\freshshop\successfullogin.php on line
>   11
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Freshshop Free Website Template -
>   Free-CSS.com\freshshop\successfullogin.php on line 13

```
UPDATE
$xml = simplexml_load_file('users.xml') or 
die("error :cannot create object");

$username='neem88';
$pwd='dbhcasvc';
$query=sprintf('/users/user[ username="%s" and password="%s" ]', $username, 
$pwd );


libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query( $query );

if( $col->length > 0 ){
foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->id;
}
```

Comment: two things  to note there, bearing in mind I have never used `simplexml_load_file` or any of it's associated methods. 
Firstly I would imagine that `simplexml_load_file` will create an `Object` which you CANNOT load into `DOMDocument` using `->loadXML` or other... These two classes ( `simplexml` and `DOMDocument` ) are not interchangable - you might be better simply doing `$dom->load('users.xml')`



Secondly: The XPath expression does not match the example I gave - you need two leading slashes - ie: `//users/user` rather than `/users/user`

Comment: @RamRaider..thank you loadss..it works..i used load('users.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were quite close with your XPath expression but you have it slightly wrong. You are trying to match on two child elements so the XPath query should have both elements within the `[ square braces ]`

The query would be of the form:

```
//users/user[ username="X" and password="Y" ]
```

putting it all together

```
$strxml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <username>mygirl</username>
        <password>mygirl1234</password>
        <email>mygirl@hotmail.com</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>2</id>
        <username>mybanana</username>
        <password>myb4n4n4</password>
        <email>mybanana@hotmail.com</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>3</id>
        <username>mytrumpet</username>
        <password>mytrumpet</password>
        <email>mytrumpet@hotmail.com</email>
    </user>
</users>';


$username='mybanana';
$pwd='myb4n4n4';

/* put both elements and values within square braces - combine with AND */
$query=sprintf('//users/user[ username="%s" and password="%s" ]', $username, $pwd );


libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->loadXML( $strxml );
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query( $query );

if( $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

This will output

```
2 mybanana myb4n4n4 mybanana@hotmail.com
```

You should be able to adapt this to `simple_xml` very easily I would imagine...

Comment: i used the codes you have given but it seems it does not query although the contents of the file is loaded

Comment: Would you care to share what / how you implemented this?

Comment: i have posted an update in which i have put the codes i have used